# How to specify VMware vFabric configuration?

Tags: eclipse, vmware, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

I've installed SpringSource Tools suite and that automatically installs the VMWare vFabric Server as the default test Server.

On my project, when I select "Run on Server" it complains that the /Servers/VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.5-config file is missing.

What's going on here?  I checked the physical directory and it was not there.  Am I missing something in the STS setup?

Answer (score 1):

> ...the /Servers/VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.5-config file is missing... I checked the physical directory and it was not there.

In my installation of STS (SpringSource Tool Suite 2.8.1 which includes VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.6) the configuration files for the server instance which is configured by default in STS is located in:

```
STS_INSTALLATION_DIR\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.6.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\conf
```

If you couldn't find it, you may have been looking in one of the Tomcat directories instead of inside the "spring-insight-instance" directory.

Comment: Thanks @zaidaus, but I'm pretty sure I checked both dirs, it seemed to be completely missing from my drive

Comment: Here's how: http://www.programmingforliving.com/2012/08/vmware-vfabric-tc-server-setup-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Once STS addon is installed, restart eclipse. You will be presented with a spring dashboard. Click on the extension tab. Choose TC Server and then install. This should solve the problem. You will see the Server automatically installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  It turned out that the "Servers" project was closed in the STS Explorer window.

Once I re-opened the Servers project, and restarted the workbench, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the steps to Installation & Config of VM Ware TC server for Springs Tools Suite(STS)

1. Download tcServer Developer’s Edition – current version is 2.5.1
2. Make a directory for tcServer (such as /opt/tcserver or c:\tcserver)
3. Unzip the downloaded file into that directory
4. Type at command line in your tcServer directory (.sh for unix/mac, .bat for Windows): tcruntime-instance.sh create myInsight -t insight
5. Start STS
6. From menu: File > New > Other… > Server > Server
7. Scroll to VMware, choose VMware vFabric tcServer 2.5
8. Click Configure Runtime Environments link
9. Add new tcServer, setting the location to your tcServer directory, press OK
10. Choose the newly configured Server Runtime Environment from the drop down